# Add unique message to each incorrect answers in Learndash

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, learndash

Currently for question, Learndash only allow to add an message to the correct answer & a generic message for all of the incorrect answer. How do i write a unique message for each of the incorrect answers.

I tried adding a script to the text editor. It works when I test it in codepen but it doesn't seem to run on the Wordpress.

```
<div>
<p id="answerMessage">Answer</p>
<div> 
<script>
function() {
  const answerMessage = document.getElementById('answerMessage');
  const labelElement = document.querySelector('li.wpProQuiz_questionListItem label.is-selected');

  if (labelElement) {
    const inputElement = labelElement.querySelector('input.wpProQuiz_questionInput');
    const selectedValue = inputElement.value;

// 3 is the correct answer
    const answerMessages = {
      "1": "Explanation 1",
      "2": "Explanation 2",
      "4": "Explanation 3",
    };

    if (selectedValue in answerMessages) {
      answerMessage.innerText = answerMessages[selectedValue];
    }
  }
};
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

It would be great if I can add an extra field below each answer on the question page. Unfortunately I'm not too familiar with PHP.